# Impure pipe cannot detect changes of binded variables and work only once

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-pipe

I am using a WYSIWYG editor in angular and previewing its format under the editor. But it is not exactly showing some styles. It is cutting off some portion giving this warning sign **sanitizing HTML stripped some content**. So i implemeted a custom pipe for showing the exact HTML. the solution of custom pipe is in [this link](https://medium.com/@AAlakkad/angular-2-display-html-without-sanitizing-filtering-17499024b079)

the pipe is transforming and keeping the content exact in  WYSIWYG for the first time when the component loaded as it has default value bound to a variable. But when I start to edit in WYSIWYG editor then the style disappeares.

code of custom pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'keepHtml', pure: false })
export class EscapeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(content:string) {
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(content);
    }
}
```

code where pipe applied

```
<ng-template ngbPanelContent>
    <div [innerHTML]="problemDescription | keepHtml "> 
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

the WYSIWYG editor:
[image: wysiwyg editor]

expected preview for the first time:
[image: expected]:

error in formatting when changed something in the wsiwyg editor and variable data changed:
[image: error]
**Update 1**
Actually pipe is triggering every time i change value but somehow

> sanitizing HTML stripped some content

is triggering

Comment: Try remove `pure: false` from your class decorator

Comment: already tried does not work